# How to resize an image to a specific dimension with original resolution using CSS?

Tags: css

I am having an situation to display an image resized to a specified dimension with original resolution using HTML and CSS alone. Is there any way to do this.

I've tried with the below code:

Code :

```
<div style="background-image: url(img.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 50px; background-repeat:no-repeat; width:100px; height:100px;">
```

Is it the correct method? or is there any other alternative.

Comment: Do you mean with original aspect ratio rather than original resolution?

Comment: No not like that, what i'm expecting is the image shouldn't compress when compared to the original

Comment: You will need to post an example with a clear explanation of what you expect to see and what you are actually seeing and how it does not meet your requirements.

Comment: Actually here what i'm doing is just displaying an image as a background and position is given as center, so it just displays the center part of that image. But what i need is to resize the original image to the given dimension with opproximately simillar resolution to the original image instead of displaying the center part of the image.

Comment: You keep mentioning "resolution" but I'm not sure it's what you mean. Describe what you mean without using the word "resolution".

Comment: what i meant is expecting an image with original clarity, it shouldn't shrink or compress.

Comment: I dont understand... but maybe the solution is using a <img height="x" width="x" src="yourimg.jpg"></img>

Comment: if we give "width" and "height", then we may not get the original clarity right?

Comment: If you don't want the image to shrink or compress then don't add width and height values.

Answer (score 0):

If you make an image bigger you have to fill the additional space with *something*.

You can stretch the image to fill the larger dimensions, which must *infer* new pixels from the original pixels through any of several algorithms. You *can't* get the "original clarity" when you do this, although you can get "good enough" depending on your situation and what you find acceptable.

To keep the same clarity/resolution you have to fill the additional space with something else, rather than stretching the image - one possibility is to tile the image to fill the space, but then of course it's not the same image. For a background image tiling is often acceptable when the image is designed to tile.

You can't make something from nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-size an image on the fly and get the same resolution, the resolution will either be the same (same dimensions), larger (smaller dimensions than original) or smaller (larger dimensions than original). You will need to process the image with something like PHP to keep the same resolution.

If you are talking about aspect ratio you CAN do it with just HTML/CSS but you need some sort of server side processor to determine the correct width/height pairs depending on your final output size. BUT by doing this your resolution will change as noted above you will need at least two DIVs in order  to change the image size properly:

`<div class="div_wrapper" style="overflow:hidden"><div class="image_wrapper" style="top:xxx;left:xxx;"><img src="..." style="width:xxx;height:xxx;"></div></div>`

Obviously you need to make sure the height/width is not shorter then the div_wrapper otherwise the background will show.